# A class of self-similar infinitely divisible distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

For $\alpha\in (0,2]$ denote $F_{\alpha}$ the class of all probability measures $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R},$ such that for any Borel set $A\subset \mathbb{R}$

$\mu(A)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\mathbf{1}_A(\frac{x+y}{2^{1/\alpha}})\mu(dx)\mu(dy).$

Every $\mu\in F_{\alpha}$ is infinitely divisible. For $\alpha=2$ $F_2$ is the class of all centered Gaussian measures. I'm interested in the case $\alpha\in (1,2).$ In this case Gaussian component of $\mu\in F_{\alpha}$ is zero and Levy-Khintchine formula has following form:

$\hat{\mu}(\xi)=\exp(\frac{i\xi}{1-2^{1-1/\alpha}}\int_{2^{-1/\alpha}<|y|\leq 1}yM(dy)+\int_{\mathbb{R}}(e^{i\xi x}-1-i\xi \mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}(|y|)y)M(dy)),$

where Levy measure $M$ satisfies relation

$M(2^{-1/\alpha}A)=2M(A), \ A\subset \mathbb{R}.$

The problem is to construct for each $\varepsilon>0$ a measure $\mu\in F_{\alpha}$ such that $\mu(-\infty,-\varepsilon)=0.$

Actually the problem is to define suitable measure on the set $\{y: 2^{-1/\alpha}<|y|\leq 1\}$ for it uniquely defines a Levy measure $M$ with needed properties. But even in the simplest case when I start from Dirac measure at point 1 and, respectively, Levy measure $M=\sum_{m\in \mathbb{Z}}2^m \delta_{2^{-m/\alpha}}$ I can't produce all the calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to understand.

With your candidate for the L\'evy measure, for $\alpha\in(1,2)$, the integral

$\int_0^1 x^2dM=\sum_{m=0}^\infty 2^m (2^{-m/\alpha})^2 < \infty$

converges, since $1-\frac{2}{\alpha}<0$, but the integral

$\int_0^1 xdM=\sum_{m=0}^\infty 2^m 2^{-m/\alpha}$

diverges, since $1-\frac{1}{\alpha}>0$, right?

So $M$ is a L\'evy measure, and there exists a L\'evy process. But your L\'evy process is not a subordinator, because the second integral diverges. Since each part of the L\'evy triple is uniquely determined, you can not add a drift that would turn your process into subordinator, either. Doesn't this mean that the support of your L\'evy process is neither bounded below, nor bounded above? I.e.,you can not have $\mu((-\infty,-\varepsilon))=0$ for any $\varepsilon$?

Comment: $1-2/\alpha<0,$ so the integral converges and $M$ is a Levy measure. Moreover, with such $M$ the distribution is in the $F_{\alpha}$ and is not $\alpha$-stable. So, maybe, such measures exist.

Comment: Oops, sorry, you are right.

Comment: Thank you, I think I've understood that such measure can't exist. If $\mu\in F_{\alpha}$ and $\mu(-\infty,-\varepsilon)=0,$ then we simply consider $\nu=\mu\ast\delta_{\varepsilon}$ and get infinitely divisible distribution on $[0,\infty)$ with Levy measure $M$ such that $\int^1_0 xM(dx)=\infty.$ This is a contradiction

Comment: Yes, your Levy process exists, but it can not satisfy your condition on the support. Btw, such Levy processes, whose Levy measure are supported on $(0,+\infty)$ (or $(-\infty,0)$) are called spectrally positive (or spectrally negative), see, e.g., http://page.math.tu-berlin.de/~papapan/papers/introduction.pdf (this contains only their definition, but nothing about their properties).